# probleme with while in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, while-loop, phantomjs

I want to make a script that will allow me PhantomJS automatically visit web pages I want, its the source code and saves it moves to the next link.
For now I get to visit the link and save the source code, but the problem is that my loop not working properly she visits a link and sometimes it in any visit.

I would be grateful for the assistance provided, it is an internship project that I must return quickly!

Here my code:

```
var NombreSaison = 8;
var NombreEpisode = 9;
var saisonActuel = 1;
var episodeActuel = 1;

while(NombreEpisode < episodeActuel)
{
    function waitFor(testFx, onReady, timeOutMillis) {
        var maxtimeOutMillis = timeOutMillis ? timeOutMillis : 3000, //< Default Max Timout is 3s
            start = new Date().getTime(),
            condition = false,
            interval = setInterval(function() {
                if ( (new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition ) {
                    // If not time-out yet and condition not yet fulfilled
                    condition = (typeof(testFx) === "string" ? eval(testFx) : testFx()); //< defensive code
                } else {
                    if(!condition) {
                        // If condition still not fulfilled (timeout but condition is 'false')
                        console.log("'waitFor()' timeout");
                        phantom.exit(1);
                    } else {
                        // Condition fulfilled (timeout and/or condition is 'true')
                        console.log("'waitFor()' finished in " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + "ms.");
                        typeof(onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady(); //< Do what it's supposed to do once the condition is fulfilled
                        clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
                    }
                }
            }, 250); //< repeat check every 250ms
    };

    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.open("http://www.dpstream.net/serie-5907-penny-dreadful-saison-1-episode-01-FR.html", function (status) 
    {
        // Check for page load success
        if (status !== "success") 
        {
            console.log("Unable to access network");
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Wait for 'signin-dropdown' to be visible
            waitFor(function() 
            {
                // Check in the page if a specific element is now visible
                return page.evaluate(function() 
                {
                    return $(".piedpage").is(":visible");
                });
            }, function() 
            {
                var fs = require('fs');
                var path = 'C:\\PhantomJS\\Fichier\\episode_1.html';
                var js = page.evaluate(function () { return document; });
                fs.write(path, js.all[0].outerHTML, 'w');
                console.log("Succes.");
                episodeActuel++;
                phantom.exit();
            });        
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: if `var NombreEpisode = 9;` and `var episodeActuel = 1;` then `while(NombreEpisode < episodeActuel)` never executes

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS's `page.open()` is asynchronous. That means that as soon as you call it, the next statement is executed. This means that the whole while loop is iterated through before the `page` even began loading the first page. In fact, only the last page will be loaded, because calling `page.open()` a second time will discard the first invocation in process.

There are two ways to solve this:

- Create a new `page` for every invocation (not recommended)
- Use recursion: define a function that does your thing for a single iteration and call with the next iteration after you've done with this iteration. If there are no more iterations, you can finally call `phantom.exit()`.

Be sure to look out for not exiting prematurely like you currently do after the first iteration.

Comment: Thanks for your message, how to do this ?

Comment: I won't provide you with the code, but you can get some inspiration [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31420803).