# PhantomJS downloading many sites starts to copy same site after first few downloads

Tags: phantomjs

This code continues to download the same site on a loop from a list of thousand pages. Couldn't find any way around it. What I googled it might be a problem with split.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pageContent = fs.read('list.txt');
var arrdata = pageContent.split(/[\n]/);
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var args = system.args;
var imagelink;
var content = " ";

function handle_page(i){
    var imageLink = arrdata[i];
    page.open(imageLink, function(){
        fs.write("file"+i+".txt", page.content, 'w');
        handle_page(i+1);
    });
}
handle_page(0);
```

Comment: You don't have a stop condition like [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31422918/1816580) you've taken this code from, so it will "open" the last URL over and over again. This is my guess. Which page does it start to misbehave from?

Comment: It begins to misbehave on the 4th URL. Adding the stop condition has no effect on the outcome.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors. PhantomJS 2.x is known to hide some errors, so you should also try PhantomJS 1.9.8.

Comment: I tried using 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8 and the newest release. The errors were "SSL handshake failed" I solved my original task by using a phantomJS script to get a single site using system.arg and made a batch script type the URLs from a file.

Comment: Have you tried running the script as: `phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --web-security=false script.js`?

Comment: Yup no luck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using a batch file to fetch an URL from a file and start a phantomJS script. Note that this may take a longer time, but it was the only way I could get this to work with a large list.

Batch:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (C:\PATH\PATH\PATH\PATH\list.txt) do (
  echo %%a
  phantomjs save_script.js %%a
)
pause
```

PhantomJS **save_page.js**:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
var system = require('system');
var re = system.args[1]

page.open("http://"+re, function(){
  fs.write(re.substr(22,100)+".html", page.content, 'w');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

I used substr(22,100) to take the last part of the website URL as a unique file name. URLs were stored without http:// due to some complications with it in the code.